# Админские права бота телеграм python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-3.7

Я использую pytelegrambotapi и Python 3.7.

Я бы хотел, чтобы мой бот проверял у себя наличие админских прав на: удаление сообщений, бан пользователей.

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я взял из своего кода. Но думаю суть разберёшь:

```
def tlg_kick_user(bot, chat_id, user_id):
    '''Telegram Kick (no ban) a user of an specified chat'''
    return_code = 0
    try:
        user_data = bot.getChatMember(chat_id, user_id)
        if (user_data['status'] != "left") and (user_data['status'] != "kicked"):
            bot.kickChatMember(chat_id, user_id)
            bot.unbanChatMember(chat_id, user_id)
            return_code = 1
        else:
            return_code = -1
    except Exception as e:
        printts("[{}] {}".format(chat_id, str(e)))
        if str(e) == "Not enough rights to restrict/unrestrict chat member":
            return_code = -2
        elif str(e) == "User is an administrator of the chat":
            return_code = -3
    return return_code

if new_user["join_retries"] < 5:
                printts("[{}] Captcha not solved, kicking {} ({})...".format(chat_id,
                        new_user["user_name"], new_user["user_id"]))
                # Try to kick the user
                kick_result = tlg_kick_user(bot, new_user["chat_id"], new_user["user_id"])
                if kick_result == 1:
                    # Kick success
                    bot_msg = TEXT[lang]["NEW_USER_KICK"].format(new_user["user_name"])
                    # Increase join retries
                    new_user["join_retries"] = new_user["join_retries"] + 1
                    printts("[{}] Increased join_retries to {}".format(chat_id,
                            new_user["join_retries"]))
                    # Set to auto-remove the kick message too, after a while
                    tlg_send_selfdestruct_msg(bot, chat_id, bot_msg)
                else:
                    # Kick fail
                    printts("[{}] Unable to kick".format(chat_id))
                    if kick_result == -1:
                        # The user is not in the chat
                        bot_msg = ['Юзер не в чате'].format(
                                new_user["user_name"])
                        # Set to auto-remove the kick message too, after a while
                        tlg_send_selfdestruct_msg(bot, chat_id, bot_msg)
                    elif kick_result == -2:
                        # Bot has no privileges to ban
                        bot_msg = ['Нет прав'].format(
                                new_user["user_name"])
                        # Send no rights for kick message without auto-remove
                        try:
                            bot.send_message(chat_id, bot_msg)
                        except Exception as e:
                            printts("[{}] {}".format(chat_id, str(e)))
                    else:
                        # For other reason, the Bot can't ban
                        bot_msg = TEXT[lang]['не могу кикнуть'].format(new_user["user_name"])
                        # Set to auto-remove the kick message too, after a while
                        tlg_send_selfdestruct_msg(bot, chat_id, bot_msg)
```